# BackStack not navigating to the correct Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, fragment-backstack

Hello im trying to navigate between some fragments with addToBaackStack but having issues with it ,
Ok i will explain it in detail so there should be no confusuion

**1 :-** I have only one activity (main activity) which consist of all the other fragments and a fragment container to hold the fragments in it , i have implemented bottom navigation in the main activity ,where the bottom navigation have 5 main fragments home,following,upload,notification and profile my issues is related to the profile fragment

**2 :-** In the profile fragment i have some buttons like edit profile button which opens edit profile fragment but now when i presse back it should  navigate back to the profile fragment which it is not doing ,its is navigating to the last fragment of the bottomnavigation (which can be any other of the main fragments for eg if my last fragment is following fragment then when i press back from the edit profile fragment it goes to the following fragment )but this not happens if i put a back arrow icon in edit profile fragment then when i click the back arrow it perfectly navigate me to the profile fragments as it is not related to addToBackStack

It shows that the issue is related with my bottom navigation but i dont know how to exactly fix it

**Prifile_Fragment.java**

```
editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Fragment edit_profile = new Edit_Profile();
            assert getFragmentManager() != null;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, edit_profile);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        });
```

**MainActivity.java** // where the bottom navigation is implemented

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Deque<Integer> integerDeque = new ArrayDeque<>(4);
    boolean flag = true;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
        integerDeque.push(R.id.nav_home);
        loadFragments(new Home_Fragment());
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                item -> {
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    if (integerDeque.contains(id)) {
                        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                            integerDeque.size();
                            if (flag) {
                                integerDeque.addFirst(R.id.nav_home);
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                        integerDeque.remove(id);
                    }
                    integerDeque.push(id);
                    loadFragments(getFragment(item.getItemId()));
                    return false;
                }
        );

    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    private Fragment getFragment(int itemId) {
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
                return new Home_Fragment();
            case R.id.nav_following:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
                return new Following_Fragment();
            case R.id.nav_upload:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
                return new Upload_Fragment();
            case R.id.nav_notification:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);
                return new Notification_Fragment();
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(4).setChecked(true);
                return new Profile_Fragment();
        }
        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        return new Home_Fragment();
    }

    public void loadFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        integerDeque.pop();
        if (!integerDeque.isEmpty()) {
            loadFragments(getFragment(integerDeque.peek()));
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider to use `popBackStack` ? You can try this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it worked but there is a small issue i want that it aslo navigate to the last fragment in bottom navigation and exit after home fragment